# Calculating no. of appearances of users in frequency of 30 days in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataframe with `users` appearing on my site. So I have a dataframe like this:

```
dateTime      userId

2018-08-02    17898
2018-08-10    17898
2018-08-25    17898
2018-08-31    17898
2018-08-02    17898
2018-09-06    17898
```

Here `dateTime` is basically the first day of appearance in that respective month. So I want to set a threshold of 30 days from their first day of appearance and count how many no. of days, the person has appeared.

So my expected dataframe would be something like this:

```
userId   n_days_appeared   total_days  first_appearance
17898     4                  30         2018-08-02
```

For every user I want something like this.

So if the person has first appeared on say 5th of August then his 30 days will be 4th September, so I want to calculate how many no. of days has that person appeared in the next 30 days from his appearance.

Comment: You want to count the number of times a user has appeared in a given month, with `first_appearance` being the first date of appearance for the user in that month? Are you sure your `user_id` column is right?

Comment: not in a given month, within next 30 days from his/her first date of appearance. I have mentioned it clearly in the question. And yes, `userId` is correct, or else how will you `.groupby`?

Comment: //Here dateTime is basically the first day of appearance in that respective month.// So it is possible to have multiple records where you have the same `dateTime` and `userId`? How can you have `2018-08-02`, `2018-08-10`, and `2018-08-25` as the "first day of appearance in that respective month" for the SAME `user_id`? What calendar is this?

Comment: didn't understand your question, there may be multiple `userId` and I want to `.groupby` `userId` and their no. of appearances in next 30 days from their first day of appearance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, maybe can use something like this

```
df = df.set_index('dateTime')

def n_days_appeared(c): 
    return c[~c.index.duplicated()].count()

def first_appearance(c):
    return c.index.min()

def total_days(c):
    return c.index.max() - c.index.min() + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')

df.groupby(['userId',pd.Grouper(freq='M')]).userId.agg([n_days_appeared, 
                                                       first_appearance, 
                                                       total_days])


                     n_days_appeared    first_appearance    total_days
userId  dateTime            
17898   2018-08-31                 4    2018-08-02          30 days
        2018-09-30                 1    2018-09-06          1 days
```

Comment: Hi, in your output first row is not correct I guess, because `first_appearance` is 2018-08-02, then how come `total_days` is 30 days and `n_days_appeared` is 4, same for the 2nd row as well. What is the diff b/w `total_days` and `n_days`. And in many cases, `n_days_appeared` is greater than `total_days`